# Select in Opera doesn't close on change event

Tags: javascript, select, opera

In Opera (and only in Opera) I have strange behavior of `select` element.
In change event, if I disable this select, it doesn't close (collapse).

```
    $('select').bind('change', function()
    {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
```

Is it some known issue of opera? So far I haven't found anything.

Comment: You should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a short delay before disabling the select, 10ms should be sufficient

Comment: not working. 
I also tried changing event to option click and it works, but not everywhere.

Comment: $('select option').bind('click', function()
{
       $('select').attr('disabled', true);
}); works also. but not in all situations. anyway, that could be a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Setting disabled attribute did not work for me, but this code works:

```
$('select').change(function() {  
  $(this).hide();
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(_this).show();
  }, 1);
});
```

Just hide select, and after one millisecond show it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a known bug in Opera (as in the "Opera Software knows about it and is working on a fix, but pretty much nobody else in the world can tell because of Opera's closed bug tracker" meaning of "known"). As far as I remember it may even be fixed for Opera 12 but I haven't double-checked that.

For workarounds, you may want to just leave it since a fix is coming in a future Opera version, using a timeout as suggested earlier should work too.