# Select box doesn't collapse after an item selected and onchage ajax event fired

Tags: ajax, drupal-7, opera

I'm using standart D7 Ajax API to load/change form elements.

So what i'm trying to get:

Make 3 dependent select boxes. I.e. when a value from the first one is selected, the second and third change. The third select box depends on the second one.

Everything work ok in all browsers except Opera for Win [no problem with Linux] (I'm using v11.51).
When you select an item (in Opera) from the select box, it doesn't collapse though ajax event is fired and data is loaded successfully.

Is there any way to collapse the select box after the event if fired?

Here is the php code for the form:

```
  $form['type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _bp_filter_get_types(),
    '#attributes' => array('onReady' => "alert('Hello!');return false;"),
    '#prefix' => '<p>',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'bp_filters_header_group_js',
      'wrapper' => 'bp-filters-header-group',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    ),
  );
  $form['brand'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $brand_options,
    '#prefix' => '<span id="bp-filters-header-group"><p id="bp-filters-header-brand">',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
    '#disabled' => $brand_disabled,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'bp_filters_header_group2_js',
      'wrapper' => 'bp-filters-header-group2',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    ),
  );
  $form['series'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _bp_filter_get_series($type_tid, $brand_tid),
    '#prefix' => '<span id="bp-filters-header-group2"><p id="bp-filters-header-series">',
    '#suffix' => '</p>',
    '#disabled' => $series_disabled,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'bp_filters_header_submit_js',
      'wrapper' => 'bp-filters-header-submit',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'none',
      'progress' => array('type' => 'none'),
    ),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => $submit_classes),
    '#value' => '',
    '#prefix' => '<p id="bp-filters-header-submit">',
    '#suffix' => '</p></span></span>',
    '#disabled' => $submit_disabled,
  );
```

Comment: See my reply on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684991/select-in-opera-doesnt-close-on-change-event for the good and bad news..

Answer (score 0):

Opera has got this bug starting with v10 for Windows. I spent 3 hours struggled this and gave the nothing result. I think there aren't sane ways to win it =(

Comment: Thanks. Is there any "unsane" solution?

Comment: I've seen somewere a solution that supposed insering a delay after click. Though didn't test